# Recording sound and getting the frequency of any given point

Tags: audio-recording, software, frequency

Not entirely sure if this question goes on this site, but I think it covers this one more than the others.

I need to record some audio of human speech and find the frequency of the audio at least 100 times a second, 1000 is better. I want the frequencies to be output somewhere in a list so that I can copy+paste them for another use, and maybe delete or mark them from the list so I don't lose track of where I am.

What (preferably free) software should I use?

Comment: Human speech isn't just a single frequency. If you ask someone to sing an A, you'll get a 440 Hz component, but also lots of harmonics (at multiples of the base frequency). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Frequencies are a spectrum from 0Hz up to approximately 20kHz. To obtain spectra of sound samples, you will need an implementation of an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) library.

For the application you are describing, you will need to use something like Matlab or Octave.